# Why is there no bone in the armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

When I import armature, in every tutorial I've seen, there is an option table to the armature like:

[image: what I want]

But when I try, I only get:

[image: what I get]

Is there Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The other options are from the *Rigify* addon. It is shipped with Blender by default, and you can enable it under *Edit > Preferences > Addons*.